# Typing hinting in parent class for a method that returns object of any child class

Tags: python

I have created an API, where a lot of functionality is implemented in a base class from which several subclasses inherit. The method of the base class will always return an object of the same type as the child class, when called through the child class. I'm struggling to figure out, how to correctly type hint the output of the different methods

As a simple example, say I have the following classes:

```
from copy import deepcopy


class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: str) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def copy(self):
        return deepcopy(self)


class SubClass(BaseClass):
    def __init__(self, x: float, a: str, b: str) -> None:
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.x = x
```

How should I type hint `BaseClass.copy()` such that it becomes clear that it will return a `SubClass` object if called from a `SubClass` object? (and etc. for any other class derived from `BaseClass`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar):

```
from copy import deepcopy
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T")

class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self, a: str, b: str) -> None:
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def copy(self: T) -> T:
        return deepcopy(self)
```

While `T` itself is declared with no restrictions, it is constrained through the annotation of `self`, so `copy` will return an object of the same type as its corresponding instance.